# random iteration over the items of the list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to iterate randomly over some given items in my list
for example:

```
items = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
for item in items:
    print(random.shuffle(items))
```

I want in each iteration it splits out a random item from my list but everytime it gives 'None'

Answer (score 3):

`random.shuffle()` shuffles the list in-place and it returns `None`.

You need to:

```
import random

items = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

for item in random.sample(items,3):  # get list of n=3 random shuffled values no dupes
    print(item)

# or

random.shuffle(items)   # shuffle in place (might get the same order as well)
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

See differences between:

- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.shuffle (in place)
- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample  (no dupes)
- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.choices (maybe dupes)

Comment: I'd suggest replacing `random.sample(items,3)` with `random.sample(items,len(items))` for a generic solution - but in this particular case we all know there always will be exactly 3 items anyway ;-)